# Angularjs load after initial json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I need to get the information before it is available. I have a varibale `var myId`. I need this varible to pass `myapp.run()`
I have 2 controllers for 2 different pages.

```
var myId; // I need this variable
afroEarthApp.controller('afroEarthMainCtrl',['$scope','$http','$location','$cookies', '$rootScope', function($scope, $http, $location, $cookies, $rootScope) {
    $http.get('js/afro.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.myDataFirst = data;
        $scope.singleNiche = $scope.myDataFirst.US;
        $rootScope.header = $scope.singleNiche;
        $rootScope.myDataVar = $scope.myDataFirst.US;
    });
    $scope.setCountry = function (choise) {
        switch (choise){
            case "US" : $scope.singleNiche = $scope.myDataFirst.US;
                break;
            case "UK" : $scope.singleNiche = $scope.myDataFirst.UK;
                break;
            case "SA" : $scope.singleNiche = $scope.myDataFirst.SA;
                break;
            case "CAN" : $scope.singleNiche = $scope.myDataFirst.CAN;
                break;
            case "AU" : $scope.singleNiche = $scope.myDataFirst.AU;
                break;
        }
        $cookies.put("myCountry", choise);
        $rootScope.header = $scope.singleNiche;
    };
    $rootScope.bodylayout = "home-page";
    myId = $scope.singleNiche // here
}]);
afroEarthApp.controller('SingleCtrl',['$scope','$http', '$location', '$routeParams', 'Single', '$cookies', '$rootScope', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams, Single, $cookies, $rootScope) {
  $scope.niche = $routeParams.niche;
    $rootScope.bodylayout = "single-page";
    var url = 'sites/'+$routeParams.niche+'.json';
    Single.get({niche: $routeParams.niche}, function (data) {
        $scope.singleFirst = data;
        $scope.singleNiche = $scope.singleFirst.US;
        var getCountry = String($cookies.get("myCountry"));
        $scope.setCountry = function (choice) {
            switch (choice) {
                case "US" :
                    $scope.singleNiche = $scope.singleFirst.US;
                    break;
                case "UK" :
                    $scope.singleNiche = $scope.singleFirst.UK;
                    break;
                case "SA" :
                    $scope.singleNiche = $scope.singleFirst.SA;
                    break;
                case "CAN" :
                    $scope.singleNiche = $scope.singleFirst.CAN;
                    break;
                case "AU" :
                    $scope.singleNiche = $scope.singleFirst.AU;
                    break;
            }
            $rootScope.header = $scope.singleNiche;
        }
        $scope.setCountry(getCountry);

    })
    $rootScope.header = $scope.singleNiche;
    myId = $scope.singleNiche; // here
}]);
afroEarthApp.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
       ...some code...
       console.log(myId) // undefined
       console.log(myId.id) // undefined
       ...some code...
    });
});
```

Can you help me.

Comment: You need to make it global, try assigning it to window

Comment: I tried. It didn't help me. The problem with reception data from JSON. When I try to get data it isn't available yet. All my pages work good, they recieve data from this JSON. I have only one problem  with transfer this variable(with data from JSON) from my `app.controller` to `app.run`.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you wish to do with that variable and what exactly is the issue?

Comment: I have 7 JSONs. In the JSON I have array with countries, in the country I have Id for backend(platform). I need get this Id and put to the futher js code for backend(platform) in the `app.run`.

Comment: based on what I see everything in that code piece should work.. maybe try assigning the $scope.singleFirst.XX to myId in the switch case and assign myId to singleNiche afterwards. Does everything inside your controller and the function work properly?

Comment: All work. Only I can get this variable with personal id. When I tried to do this `myId = $scope.singleFirst.XX` outside `get` I see this `TypeError: Cannot read property 'US' of undefined` . https://github.com/mak633/afroearth/  - all my files. Code for backend in the index.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I unbderstood what the problem is , `$scope.myDataFirst = data;` is set inside the `$http.get()` & since this is a asynchronous call, it would not set `data` immediately.

but Javascript engine doesnt wait for the `asynchronous` call to complete, hence `$scope.myDataFirst.US;` throws errors which in turn sets undefined value to `myId = $scope.singleNiche // here`.

---

## Solution:

- Move all code inside `success` callback like below.
- You haven't handled error handling flow in your code, which is essentialy when working with `ajax` calls

**JS CODE:**

```
$http.get('js/afro.json').then(
   successHandler,
   errorHandler
);

function successHandler(data){
   $scope.myDataFirst = data;
   $scope.singleNiche = $scope.myDataFirst.US;
   $rootScope.header = $scope.singleNiche;
   $rootScope.myDataVar = $scope.myDataFirst.US;

   $scope.setCountry = function (choise) {
      switch (choise){
        case "US" : $scope.singleNiche = $scope.myDataFirst.US;
            break;
        case "UK" : $scope.singleNiche = $scope.myDataFirst.UK;
            break;
        case "SA" : $scope.singleNiche = $scope.myDataFirst.SA;
            break;
        case "CAN" : $scope.singleNiche = $scope.myDataFirst.CAN;
            break;
        case "AU" : $scope.singleNiche = $scope.myDataFirst.AU;
            break;
     }
     $cookies.put("myCountry", choise);
     $rootScope.header = $scope.singleNiche;
  };
    $rootScope.bodylayout = "home-page";
    myId = $scope.singleNiche;
}

function errorHandler(error){
   //show error message when async call fails.
}
```

Comment: It doesn't help me. The code is work , but I still can't get `myId` . I see only in the `function successHandler(data)` but outside is `undefinde`. http://i.imgur.com/9soB8pP.jpg?1

Comment: Yes thats exactly what iam saying, when Javascript engine runs your script, it triggers the `$http.get()` and continues with following statements, it doesnt wait for `successHandler()` to  execute, due to which when you `console.log(myId);` outside `successHandler()` it wont work at that instance. check this jsfiddle to know more how ajax calls work, http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/WQXXT/1467/

Comment: Ok. I got you. But what should I to do? I need this variable. Maybe do you know another way? Set `$http.get()` outside controller or use REST or something else?

Comment: I need put this variabl to `app.run` or `index.html` inside tag `script`

Comment: well if you need to use the value `myId` for text field then set it to `$scope` and access the same via `ng-model` inside `input` tag(two-way binding).

Comment: btw, why would you need to refer this variable at `.run` ? any specific reason ?

Comment: I need something like this in the scrip tag `index.html` - `var wld_app_id =  myId;` Futher I have js code for backend(platform).

Comment: I don't understand about `input` and `ng-model`. Can you give me an example. I have js code in the `index.html` for backend. This code use id ` var wld_app_id = myId; ` myId I need get from JSON.

Comment: @MaksymKrugliachenko: you can share values if you set it to the global scope `$rootScope`, check this codepen & click on any server side language , browser console will log `$rootScope` value before & after edit. http://codepen.io/dreamweiver/pen/zqPzJv

Comment: https://github.com/mak633/afroearth/blob/master/index-sample.html I have js code in the index.html for backed(platform).

Comment: i have no idea how to do that, but atleast you can access that variable at `.run()`

Comment: yes, I can put this code to `.run()`. But how can I get it from `$http.get`?

Comment: you already have `$rootscope` in your controller `afroEarthApp.controller('afroEarthMainCtrl',['$scope','$http','$location','$cookies', '$rootScope', function($scope, $http, $location, $cookies, $rootScope) {`. so just set the value  `$rootScope.myId = $scope.singleNiche;` then try to refer the same variable inside `.run()`,  you can refer the code pen which i shared earlier to know how to do this.

Comment: I set in the `.controller $http.get$` this `$rootScope.myId = $scope.singleNiche;` Then in the `.run()` I do `console.log($rootScope.myId); // undefined`. I tried this way.

Comment: looks like the `.run()` will be executed first and then it goes to `.controller()`. so the only option i can see here is to call the entire `$http.get()` inside `.run()`. so that you can access `myId` there

Comment: Thanks for all. Your advices helped me a lot.